# Image not shown in PyQt4: Debugging hints

Tags: python, pyqt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicspixmapitem

I'm writing an Application with PyQt where a lot of images are displayed. I use basically the same draw Routine for all my images, which works fine except for one image, which resides in a tab widget. Here the drawing routine:

```
def draw(self, array, scene, pixmap_pointer, view):
    qim = self.create_QImage(array) # routine which converts numpy array to qimage
    image = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
    pixmap_pointer.setPixmap(image)
    view.setScene(scene)
```

This routine is working for all my other QImageViews/Scenes, so the error must be somewhere else. I use ipdb with pyqtRemoveInputHook() for debugging, but it is difficult to inspect the objects, since there is no way to display the images in the intermediate methods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. it came down to a typo, which was drawing the new image behind my actual one. Debug_trace() helped a lot to identify it, especially calling the save method of pixmap for intermediate data inspection.